# Check is user is try to swipe out of last page of ViewPager and then start a new and kill the current activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity

I have an `Activity` which extends `FragmentActivity`

```
public class SlideScreen extends FragmentActivity {


    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    ViewPager mViewPager;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slide_screen);


        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);



        OnPageChangeListener mListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                Log.i("Doing something here", "onPageSelected : "+arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {


                Log.i("My App Logs", "onPageScrolled : "+arg0+"  "+arg1+" "+arg2);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                Log.i("My App Logs", "onPageScrollStateChanged : "+arg0);
            }
        };
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mListener);

    }
...

...
}
```

I want to know when the user try to swipe out of the last page(Total 5 pages) , I cannot apply `OnSwipeOutListener`.

The `OnPageChangeListener` is not helping me as its gives `onPageSelected` as `4` when swiping from `4th` to `5th` and `4` when swiping out as well

I want to start a new `Activity` on the swiping at last page.